# play m3u8 file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I know this question was ask lot time but not get proper solution,

i have one m3u8 file which is not working in AVPlayer but if i use other m3u8 file which was already on internet that is working fine with AVPlayer ,here is my code

```
func playVideo() {
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://architectsummit.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hls/playlist-with-vtt.m3u8")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
}
```

in  above code i used m3u8 file which provided by our developer , but if i use this url 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8' in above code video is playing what is issue anyone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I oppened the .m3u8 link in browser and the manifest that is being downloaded is wrong.
The manifest response is

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI=vtt_en.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=864000,SUBTITLES="subs" 
                hls-medium.m3u8
```

and the format the manifest must be something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/video_on_demand_playlist_construction)

Server .m3u8 file does not include any playlist

Also because you use Amazon you can check some examples from Amazon [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/manifest-hls-example.html)

Comment: can you help me to get right structure of m3u8 file?

Comment: Yes I just updated my answer so you can check the correct format from amazon. For more information you need a multimedia expert...