# Why can't I play certain .m3u8 items with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avplayer

I'm working on a project where I have an instance of AVPlayer capable of playing different audio content that I retrieve from a backend, from podcast to music and streamings. Every content has two types of urls: one with mp3 and another with a m3u8 file. All the mp3 files work good. However some m3u8 files work fine and others don't. In particular, those who don't work cause the AVPlayer to crash with the error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.,
NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action.}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928748/play-m3u8-file-in-ios) it is a wrong Manifest file, which in my case is - for example - the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_64/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-64000",NAME="AAC  64",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_80/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-80000",NAME="AAC 80",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_96/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-96000",NAME="AAC 96",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=133336,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-96000"
_96/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=100641,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-64000"
_64/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=116989,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-80000"
_80/index.m3u8
```

On the Apple forum, I found [this answer](http://instantseotools.com/679862.html) which says iOS 14+ is on fault. Unfortunately I cannot test with an iOS 13 physical device.

Do you have any suggestion?

Tested on Xcode 13.1 with iPhone 7plus with iOS 15.0.2.

Comment: ther are unfortunatelly some problems with playing m3u8 on simulator. Do you have the same error on real device ?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak I tested with a real device. The iPhone 7plus I mention is a real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this issue. What worked for me was [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/selecting_subtitles_and_alternative_audio_tracks). I believe the problem was that my manifest files were structured like the following:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_64/index.m3u8", GROUP-ID="1@48000-64000",NAME="Audio 64",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
```

In particular they had `DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO`. Therefore before calling `replaceCurrentItem` I now do the following:

```
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    
    for characteristic in asset.availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions {
        if let group = asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.audible) {
            if let option = group.options.first {
                playerItem.select(option, in: group)
            }
        }
    }
```

This makes all my HLS audio playable by the AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see version in your .m3u8. Try adding #EXT-X-VERSION:03 into your playlist. `AVPlayer` does need to have version included in playlist (Android EXO player does not need it). Here is example of playlist that might work:

```
    #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:03
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_64/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-64000",NAME="AAC  64",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_80/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-80000",NAME="AAC 80",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="_96/index.m3u8",GROUP-ID="2@48000-96000",NAME="AAC 96",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=133336,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-96000"
_96/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=100641,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-64000"
_64/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=116989,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="2@48000-80000"
_80/index.m3u8
```

Comment: How would I do that? Do I have to manipulate the file or can I do it from Swift when I receive it?

Comment: At first try to verify if this is your case and those playlists that includes some version of #EXT-X-VERSION (e.g. #EXT-X-VERSION:03) work , and those without version dont. You said that some .m3u8 playlists work well, am I right ? Are you getting playlist from URL task, or are you storing them on device ? At first try to manipulate the playlist manually in text edit by adding version to it.

Comment: Right. Basically I get some urls from backend. By opening the urls in the browser I can inspect them and see the manifest (if I'm doing it right, I'm not really a multimedia expert). I see how those that are playable actually do have the version included. One url who is not playable instead has a weird situation: I get one file my_resource.m3u8 which doesn't have the version and two index.m3u8 who include many segment1.aac and do have the version within it.

Comment: If you are building some VOD service, try telling someone from backend to just add the version to playlist and you should be ready to go. It would be much easier to change playlist on backend than on device.

Comment: I'll try, thanks. I'll keep the question open in case others can contribute otherwise, I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I understand that, OK sure!